# ADMA0176E PrivilegedActionException: Application installation of {0} faild with PrivilegedActionException

Tags: websphere

when trying to add a project to my WebSphere, I get the following error:

> ADMA0176E: Application installation of {0} faild with PrivilegedActionException. Ear file path is {1}.

Any idea what I could do? According to a Google search, it could be some permission problem, but I don't know where to start at all...

Any info is really appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong/missing configuration in Websphere: application security wasn't checked in the administration console...

Answer (score 0):

Following files were missing for my project. Copying these files from another project solved the problem.

1. security.xml  at path: [ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell]
2. deployment.xml, resources.xml and variables.xml at path: [ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp]

This worked on IBM WAS 7.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked after I run the Eclipse as administrator. Just that.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was that somehow the EAR's `/META-INF/application.xml` changed from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
    <display-name>macc-ear</display-name>
    <module id="Module_1381754217072">
        <web>
            <web-uri>macc-frontend.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/macc</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
    <display-name>macc-ear</display-name>
</application>
```

I have no idea what caused this, but it seems like IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD) sometimes does things on its own.