# ADMA0176E PrivilegedActionException when publishing to IBM Websphere

Tags: maven-2, websphere, ibm-rad

I have a maven build of a multi module enterprise project. I am running WAS from RAD. In command prompt I ran

```
mvn clean
mvn install
mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse
```

The build is success. I then import it into my workspace in RAD and add project to WAS. When the server starts publishing. I get an error as pop up saying

> ADMA0176E : Application installation of MYPROJECT failed with
>   PrivilegedActionException

I am able to deploy the same project on tomcat. Also, I created a sample project and published it to WAS. So I dont understand why the application is asking for privileges. I tried enabling application security, cleared the server cache, restarted server, restarted PC. Nothing helps. I can deploy the ear through admin console, however. Only through rad I am getting issues. How do I solve this ? I tried what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003496/adma0176e-privilegedactionexception-application-installation-of-0-faild-with-p%20PrivilegedActionException) but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and could solve it by deleting the according folder in `\profiles\AppSrv1\installedApps\`. I don't think this is a general solution for this problem, but I could not find this hint on any of the other discussions for `ADMA0176E`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after making some pom.xml changes. I solved it by running Maven Update Dependencies then Maven Update Project Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Following files were missing for my project. Copying these files from another project solved the problem.

1. security.xml  at path: [ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell]
2. deployment.xml, resources.xml and variables.xml at path: [ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp]

This worked on IBM WAS 7.